# IIS 7 gives me error 500 internal server error when trying to display my XML document

Tags: xml, browser, iis-7

This is quite strange.  I have a piece of code running on my server that emits XML to the browser. When I use my dev box to access the page I get a "500 Internal Server Error" page.  After numerous diagnostic attempts, I RDPed into my server and tried to use its internal web browser.  I was able to see the xml document fine.  In know this has nothing to do with my dev browser because I tried both FF and IE and they were able to view the same XML from a mirror server.  This leads me to believe it may be some kind of IIS 7 issue.  Can any one here help?

Comment: Are you seeing the GET request in the IIS logs?  You should check your bindings,etc to make sure the correct site is getting the request

Comment: I didn't check the GET requests in the IIS logs, but I made print statements just to make sure it was going to the correct site. I also have a debug switch that dumps stuff out. It is definately going to the right site.

Comment: I inspected the headers and found that the on the server's browser, the content type was text/xml while outside it was text/html.  Weird.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer to my question.  It turns out that I am running Windows 2008 R2 and its version of IIS has a error pages section.  By default, the error responses are set to "Detailed error for local requests and custom error pages for remote requests."  This was the reason I couldn't see the xml document remotely.  I switched the setting to "Detailed errors" and it solved the problem.

You can learn more about this here: 
[IIS7 - Enabling Custom Error Pages](http://blogs.iis.net/rakkimk/archive/2008/10/03/iis7-enabling-custom-error-pages.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Just for reference, I had the same problem, and the issue what that the local folder had caching of XML files turned on, but at the same time the entire web server had XML caching turned on.

Try opening the 'Output Caching' module for the folder in question from within IIS. If you get an error, simply edit the local web.config file and remove the 'double' file extension cache setting.