# C#/IIS/MVC: Static Conetent not loading on different environments

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I have a **C# MVC 4.5 Website** where everything works as expected, until recently, when I added a new folder.

It was meant to house CMS-type applications and keep them separate from the main site. As I built these apps I checked everything on my local instance of the site, and it all looked fine.

However, since I pushed the updates to DEV, I'm getting some odd and unexpected results - displayed below.

Here's a pseudo-file structure:

```
Solution 'MySite'
    MySite
        Controllers
        Images // Images from this folder appear normally
        Models
        Scripts // Scripts from this folder load normally
        Views
        Admin
            AdminApplication
                Index.cshtml
            Shared
                admin_common.css // 500 error
                admin_common.js // 500 error
            Images
                banner.jpg // will not load
```

Keep in mind all these issue are only on Dev, everything on local is fine. It seems very weird that a css file would load, but not have any content.

This is how the styles and scripts load in the layout:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/Shared/jquery.js") // loads fine
@Scripts.Render("~/Admin/Shared/admin_common.js") // 500
@Syle.Render("~/Admin/Shared/admin_common.css") // 500
```

---

**Here's what I've tried:**

1. I looked at **log files**, but they all say the files loaded fine. I only see 200's, no 500's.
2. I looked at the **static content option in IIS**, as seen here: http://adilmughal.com/blog/2011/11/iis-7-not-loading-css-and-image/ but it's an IIS-wide option rather than folder-specific.
3. When I visit the URL of the css, I get `500: Server Error [10-0002]` so I looked for that, but the only thing that seemed useful was this, https://communities.ca.com/thread/110605407, a deep comment said their **isapi file was missing**. I checked my web.config file, and tracked down the isapi files, and they looked fine.
4. I tried the **Failed Request Tracing**, as specified here: [IIS 7 gives me error 500 internal server error when trying to display my XML document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4916343/iis-7-gives-me-error-500-internal-server-error-when-trying-to-display-my-xml-doc), but there were no logs there, even though it was on.... which is weird, but not what this question concerns.
5. I also tried **adding an httperror line to web.config** like this says: https://serverfault.com/questions/407954/how-to-diagnose-a-500-internal-server-error-on-iis-7-5-when-nothing-is-written-t. It should give better errors, but it doesn't.

What is causing my development machine to not display this necessary content?

Comment: I think it should be: ** ~/Admin/Shared/admin_common.css ** NOT ~/Admin/Scripts/admin_common.css.... You don't have a Scripts folder under ADMIN

Comment: Good catch. I'll fix that. It is just an aesthetic mistake though, that issue is not in the actual code.

Comment: Try changing bundle names (give non existing path just like JQuery bundle) for faulting css and js as paths (name) mentioned there are valid existing paths and files hence its not able to create bundle for it.  Make sure your define bundle with new name in bundle config file.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**: an unnecessary web.config file with missing isapi handlers.

---

When I first started the new folder, Admin, I wasn't sure how it would work. I read somewhere that it would need it's own web.config file. So I copied a bare-bones web.config file from somewhere into the new folder.

Later on, I changed the name of it to web.bonfig, to make it inactive (b for backup).

My current theory is perhaps there is a different precedence of conflicting config files on the servers (but where would something like that even be defined?). This morning I changed the file name to web.bonfig.backup-ignore from a Windows Explorer window and that seemed to have fixed my issue.

BTW web.bonfig only had one handler defined in system.webServer. This would suggest that solution 3 in my question was the correct solution, but I was looking in the wrong config file.